# React JS event.target.value sometimes null sometimes what it needs to be

Tags: reactjs, button, onclick

I have a table with the rows mapped from an array, and an edit button for each row. I have specified a value to every button using map(value, index).

```
var selected;

 handleUpdate = (e) => {
    e.persist();
    selected = filteredresults[e.target.value];
    this.setState({
      updateform: true,
      viewuser: false,
    });
  };

 <Button
   type="button"
   color="primary"
   value={index}
   onClick={(e) => this.handleUpdate(e)}   Or   onClick={this.handleUpdate}
   style={{ width: "5px" }}>
   <EditIcon />
 </Button>
```

When I click the button, `e.target.value` is sometimes null or undefined, and sometimes the index value.

I read about event pooling in react, so I added `e.persist()` but the random behavior still remains.

Why "SOMETIMES"? The expected behavior should be the same everytime.

Comment: try commenting out `e.persist`, and see what happens.

Comment: I added  e.persist beacuse it wasn't working everytime.  Sometimes it was sometimes not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    try passing the value of index directly as a parameter to handleUpdate method as shown below. 
Also, you can remove the e.persist() call. That's irrelevant.
    handleUpdate = (e,value) => {
        selected = filteredresults[value];
        this.setState({
          updateform: true,
          viewuser: false,
        });
      };
    
     <Button
       type="button"
       color="primary"
       onClick={(e) => this.handleUpdate(e,index)} 
       style={{ width: "5px" }}>
       <EditIcon />
     </Button>
```

Comment: Hey, this solution works, my bad, this was so simple. But I am still curious about its random behaviour.